# Secondary color not updated in filter

Tags: attributes, filter, color-swatches

I've set up two color attributes 1 for creating configurable products with the provided colors form the manufacturers, these colors come with a lot of variations.
The 2nd attribute is with main colors for search and filter options.

The problem when I select a color swatch in the filter from the 2nd attribute the product images won't update. If I do the same with the 1st attribute the images do change.
If tried several different options and names of the attributes and colors but no result so far.
I prefer a color swatch for the 2nd attribute and the first attribute must be a image for selection on the product page. Any ideas?